# Automatic move from local variables when variable is rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++20

According to cppreference, in return statement, local rvalue references should be moved from in C++20:

> Automatic move from local variables and parameters
>
> - If expression is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names a variable whose type is either
> - **a non-volatile object type or
>   a non-volatile rvalue reference to object type
>   (since C++20)**

I tried the second bullet point ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/kVPErC)):

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
    Bar() = default;

    Bar(const Foo &) {
        printf("copy!\n");
    }
    Bar(Foo &&) {
        printf("move!\n");
    }
};

Bar foo() {
    Foo f;
    Foo &&rf = static_cast<Foo &&>(f);
    return rf;
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

I expected that this program prints `move!`. But actually, both clang and gcc prints `copy!`. Is this something which haven't been implemented yet in compilers? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: What is the purpose of having 2 classes in this example?

Comment: @DanielLangr: no avoid NRVO.

Comment: Considering it prints "move!" when `f` is returned, and that compiler vendors are still deep in the process of implementing C++20, you haven't misunderstood anything.

Comment: Check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20#Compiler_support), it is available only on MSVC since 19.24 version - *DR: Implicit move for more local objects and rvalue references*.

Comment: @rafix07 This basically is an answer.

Comment: @rafix07: thank you, it is good to know about that table!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this something which haven't been implemented yet in compilers?

[Not implemented yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (look for P1825), you understand the rule correctly. But let's go through it to be sure. The specific standard text here is in [[class.copy.elision]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3):

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a non-volatile object **or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type**. In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the *expression* in a `return` ([stmt.return]) or `co_­return` ([stmt.return.coroutine]) statement is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an implicitly movable entity declared **in the body** or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, or
> - if the operand of a *throw-expression* is a [...]

`rf` is an rvalue reference (check) to `Foo` (non-volatile object type, check), which makes it an implicitly movable entity. In `return rf;`, that's an *id-expression* that names an implicitly movable entity (check) declared in the body of the function (check). So, we move instead of copy.